# Matching pair of entities with fixed values

Tags: sesam

Is it possible to match and merge entities in a dataset where one of the entities has code 1 and the other entity has code 2? I tried to solve this using "merge" and "eq", "code", "code"+1, but this merges in the entity with code 3 (which is not what I want).

```
{
  "_id": "sample-data",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "a1",
      "name": "A",
      "code": 1
    }, {
      "_id": "a2",
      "name": "A",
      "code": 2
    }, {
      "_id": "a3",
      "name": "A",
      "code": 3
    }, {
      "_id": "b1",
      "name": "B",
      "code": 1
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's several ways to do this by using ["if"], but I would prefer using a simple comparison using ["in"]:

```
{
  "_id": "merge-sample",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "merge",
    "datasets": ["sample-data sd"],
    "equality": [
      ["eq",
        ["in", "sd.code",
          ["list", 1, 2]
        ],
        ["in", "sd.code",
          ["list", 1, 2]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "identity": "first",
    "strategy": "compact",
    "version": 2
  }
}
```

Running this on your test data will result in a dataset looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "$ids": [
      "~:sample-data:a1",
      "~:sample-data:a2",
      "~:sample-data:b1"
    ],
    "sample-data:code": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "sample-data:name": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$ids": [
      "~:sample-data:a3"
    ],
    "sample-data:code": 3,
    "sample-data:name": "A"
  }
]
```

Comment: I see now that the problem was not described correctly. The idea was to _not_ merge the entities that had different codes. So the desired output is to merge a1 with a2, and leave a3 and b1 unmerged.